Install a specific version of snap with Ansible
If I need to install (upgrade to) latest version on snap (analogue of snap install foobar --classic command) with Ansible, I could use something like
- name: Install foobar snap
  community.general.snap:
    name: foobar
    classic: true
    channel: stable

But if I need to install (upgrade to) a specific non-latest version on snap (analogue of snap install foobar --classic --revision 1234 or snap refresh foobar --revision 1234 command), how to do that with Ansible?

Wouldn't that be just options?

A snap’s revision is a number assigned automatically by the Snap Store with each snap upload, giving each snap binary a unique identity within, and across, its channels. Therefore, we can use channels to install it.
For this, first we can do a
$ snap info foobar

channels:
  latest/stable:    2.59.4                 2023-05-31 (19361) 55MB -
  latest/candidate: 2.59.5                 2023-06-09 (19457) 55MB -
  latest/beta:      2.59.5                 2023-05-27 (19457) 55MB -
  2020.1/stable:    2.10.5                 2020-01-13 (19535) 42MB -

and then we can use
- name: Install foobar snap
  community.general.snap:
    name: foobar
    classic: true
    channel: 2020.1/stable

